# How to log only POST ant PATCH request from WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, logging, webclient

I'm registering the filter for logging the response from WebClient, but I would like to log only the POST and PATCH request (without plenty of GET requests on which I'm not interested in). How I can log only the specific POST and PATCH response?

The WebClient bean:

```
  @Bean
  public WebClient sfWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .filter(logResponse())
        .build();
  }
```

The logResponse filter:

```
  ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
      if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Request finished with the status: ").append(clientResponse.statusCode());
        log.debug(sb.toString());
      }
      return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can implement your own ExchangeFilterFunction like this:

```
WebClient.builder().filter((request, next) ->
        next.exchange(request).map(response -> {
            if ((request.method() == HttpMethod.POST || request.method() == HttpMethod.PATCH) && log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("Request finished with the status: ").append(response.statusCode());
                log.debug(sb.toString());
            }
            return response;
        });
    );
```

Comment: It is good, but please change `return Mono.just(response)` to `return response`. The statement `next.exhange(request)` already returns `Mono<T>`, so your whole filter function is going to return `Mono<Mono<ClientResponse>>`